# retrofit 2, распарсить ответ

Tags: android, retrofit2

Допустим в json приходит массив элементов , каждый имеет название и одно значение.`{"AAA":4.523703,"BBB":85.195162}`.  Построим POJO модель

```
        @SerializedName("AAA")
        @Expose
        private Double AAA;
        @SerializedName("BBB")
        @Expose
        private Double BBB;
```

Но мне в итоге надо в `listView` выводить  название и значение в одну строчку, значит нужен `Map` .
  Можно ли в `retrofit 2` c помощью аннотаций добиться этого? Чтобы распарился именно в `Map<String, Double> AAA = new HashMap<>()` 
 Может с этим retrofit 2 справиться или придется вручную парсить. Как вручную это сделать я знаю.

**Обновление вопроса**
Я делаю запрос

```
@GET("{date}")
Call<String> getData(@Path("date") String date, @Query("access_key") String accessKey);
```

Как видите получить я пытаюсь строку, я хочу сырой json, чтобы парсить самому. Этого у меня сделать не получилось. По идее я не должен вообще никакой конвертер использовать, но если отключить конвертеры, я получаю исключение.  Это первый вопрос. Второй вопрос в том, как парсить не самому, а использовать POJO модель. В конечном итоге нужен HashMap в котором

```
AAA = 4.523703
BBB = 85.195162
```

Какой объект должен быть  в `Call<>`

Comment: Пришел я к выводу, что придется создавать целый класс, в котором в HashMap на место ключа придется вручную ставить все названия, а  значения подтягивать из распарсенного класса.  Получится около 50 полей, в одном классе и столько же в другом. Гадость.. А есть количество полей будет меняться, то POJO модель вообще не подходит.

Comment: `Gson` умеет парсить объект прямо в `Map`. То есть Вы можете в качестве модели использовать `Map`, `HashMap` и т.п.

Comment: моя задача в том как  с помощью POJO модели получить в HashMap на первое место "AAA",  а на второе 4.523703

Comment: И да, забыл дописать, что конвертером у меня как раз Gson выбран

Comment: Это видно по аннотациям. А вот что Вы хотите не понятно, Каждое поле в отдельный `HashMap` что ли? Зачем?

Comment: нет, проблема в том, чтобы получить значение "AAA":4.523703  , я должен писать  @SerializedName("AAA") и получу я значение, и так около 50 полей, а названия "AAA"  и так далее, мне придется в HashMap вставлять самому. Я хочу получать сразу от библиотеки HashMap в котором ключ и есть "AAA" , то название по которому я парсил.

Comment: Как я понимаю в Gson нет такого метода, который возвратит HashMap в котором ключ равен названию элемента, а Value значение элемента. Такое придется ручками делать

Comment: Сам json-object - по сути и есть `Map` <имя-значение>, поэтому `Gson` запросто его сконвертит в `HashMap`, где ключами будут имена.

Comment: Gson то сможет, получил массив элементов, выставил итератор, запоминаем и название и значение по этому названию. А вот какую аннотацию в ретрофит выставить, чтобы по названию я получал не String, а HashMap. Думаю что никакую

Comment: Тогда расписывайте вопрос во всех подробностях - потому что ни черта не понятно чего Вы хотите.

Comment: более развернуто выложил вопрос

Comment: Как получить сырой ответ я понял можно либо оставлять конвертер Gson и принимать объект JsonObject , а потом его toString(). Либо вообще конвертер не использовать, а принмать ResponseBody и у него есть метод string , правда он может исключение выдать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда нужно получить "сырую" строку - используем стандартный `ResponseBody`:

```
@GET("{date}")
Call<ResponseBody> getData(@Path("date") String date, @Query("access_key") String accessKey);
```

Получаем: `String rawJson = response.body().string()`

---

Если хотим получить сразу `HashMap` и json-объект содержит только однотипные поля, `HashMap` и используем с `GsonConverter`:

```
@GET("{date}")
Call<HashMap<String, Double>> getData(@Path("date") String date, @Query("access_key") String accessKey);
```

Получаем: `HashMap<String, Double> map = response.body();`

Comment: мм,  а я пытался с помощью аннотации ретрофит получить такой Map, получая отдельно каждую пару из json. А оказывается можно было все пары разом попросить. И теперь если даже количество пар  в json от запроса к запросу разное, я получаю их все. Я думал Pojo модель только для статических json подходит, а оказывается легко можно и под динамический использовать.

Comment: А насчет сырого json я понял, в последний мой комментарий к вопросу, я там хотел узнать, как всё таки лучше. Просто метод string у ResponseBody может исключение вызвать. А если использовать JsonObject и выполнять метод toString, то проблем нет. Зачем лишнее место где может быть исключение?

Comment: Если строка - не json - Вы таким способом её не получите. И вместо маленькой проверки `response.isSuccesful()`, будет парсинг в `JsonObject` и его сериализация обратно в строку, а тоже самое исключение будет выхватывать `Gson` и отправлять в `onFailure()`

Comment: ну а если есть уверенность, что сервер только json шлет, то можно ведь использовать

Comment: Если есть такая уверенность, то это просто лишние затраты на десериализацию и сериализацию обратно, а потом снова десериализацию. Лучше сразу использовать нужную модель.

Comment: Ну да, согласен. Мне строка нужна была только чтобы распечатать в консоль. И еще не подскажите, есть возможность с помощью Gson в массив получить все ключи? имеется ввиду без значений, только ключи. Если в Вашем ответе в последнем запросе, вместо Map просто массив строк подложить, интересно чем он наполнится..

Comment: `Gson`? А так не вариант [`map.keySet()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet()) ?

Comment: ну в основном да, но иногда нужно какие то ключи удалить, а если это сделать из map они тоже пропадут. Хотелось бы и map сохранить и отдельный массив ключей иметь. Ну думаю самому тогда циклом пробежаться. Но лучше бы сразу json распарсить отдельно в map и отдельно массив ключей. Как то короче выглядит код

Comment: Короче, чем это: `ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());` ? Вместо `ArrayList` может быть другая коллекция. Или так `String[] keys = map.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);`

Comment: Ну вообще да, довольно коротко)