# Retrofit 2 null в ответе

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Ребят помогите разобраться, никак не пойму в чем ошибка

Код:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://maps.googleapis.com/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

            Call<RouteResponse> call = service.getRoute(from,to,true,"ru");

            call.enqueue(new Callback<RouteResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<RouteResponse> call, Response<RouteResponse> response) {
                    Log.e("Тут", "Тут");
//                Декодируем маршрут в точки LatLng
                    List<LatLng> mPoints = PolyUtil.decode(response.body().getPoints());
                    Log.e("Размер",String.valueOf(mPoints.size()));
                    //Строим полилинию

                    Log.e("Размер",String.valueOf(mPoints.size()));
                    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                    polylineOptions.width(4f).color(R.color.colorBlack);
                    LatLngBounds.Builder latLngBuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                    for(int i = 0;i<mPoints.size();i++){
                        polylineOptions.add((LatLng)mPoints.get(i));
                        latLngBuilder.include((LatLng)mPoints.get(i));
                    }
                    map.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
                    int size = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
                    LatLngBounds latLngBounds = latLngBuilder.build();
                    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latLngBounds,size,size,25);
                    map.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<RouteResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                }
```

Не смотрите на код, тут response.body возвращает null, как исправить?

Лог

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at com.example.danilshik.testapplication.fragments.ShopInMapWay$1.onResponse(ShopInMapWay.java:163)
                      at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 1044K, 7% free 15770K/16903K, paused 12ms+10ms, total 46ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 33ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1012K, 11% free 15779K/17543K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4
                  Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 4
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method ts.a
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve const-class 274 (Landroid/os/UserManager;) in Lts;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0010
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.os.UserManager.isUserUnlocked, referenced from method ts.a
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1154: Landroid/os/UserManager;.isUserUnlocked ()Z
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0023
```

APIService

```
@GET("maps/api/directions/json")
    Call<RouteResponse> getRoute(
            @Query(value = "origin", encoded = false) String position,
            @Query(value = "destination",encoded = false) String dectination,
            @Query("sensor") boolean sensor,
            @Query("language") String language

    );
```

RouteResponce

```
public class RouteResponse {
    public List<Route> routes;

    public String getPoints(){
        return routes.get(0).overviewPolyline.points;
    }

    class Route{
        OverviewPolyline overviewPolyline;
    }
    class OverviewPolyline{
        String points;
        }
}
```

JSON

```
{
    "geocoded_waypoints": [
        {
            "geocoder_status": "OK",
            "place_id": "ChIJs4CrATw62UMRKg9NqObeA2I",
            "types": [
                "street_address"
            ]
        },
        {
            "geocoder_status": "OK",
            "place_id": "ChIJcQYIThU62UMRmhKGs-q_q70",
            "types": [
                "route"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "bounds": {
                "northeast": {
                    "lat": 54.7380729,
                    "lng": 55.9732509
                },
                "southwest": {
                    "lat": 54.7329662,
                    "lng": 55.9581493
                }
            },
            "copyrights": "Картографические данные © 2018 Google",
            "legs": [
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "1,7 км",
                        "value": 1690
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "8 мин.",
                        "value": 470
                    },
                    "end_address": "ул. Ивана Якутова, Уфа, Респ. Башкортостан, Россия",
                    "end_location": {
                        "lat": 54.73732889999999,
                        "lng": 55.9581493
                    },
                    "start_address": "ул. Мингажева, 160/1, Уфа, Респ. Башкортостан, Россия, 450005",
                    "start_location": {
                        "lat": 54.7348831,
                        "lng": 55.9732509
                    },
                    "steps": [
                        {
                            "distance": {
                                "text": "20 м",
                                "value": 20
                            },
                            "duration": {
                                "text": "1 мин.",
                                "value": 6
                            },
                            "end_location": {
                                "lat": 54.7347061,
                                "lng": 55.9732059
                            },
                            "html_instructions": "Направляйтесь на <b>юг</b>",
                            "polyline": {
                                "points": "_lamIygstI`@F"
                            },
                            "start_location": {
                                "lat": 54.7348831,
                                "lng": 55.9732509
                            },
                            "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
                        },
                        {
                            "distance": {
                                "text": "67 м",
                                "value": 67
                            },
                            "duration": {
                                "text": "1 мин.",
                                "value": 36
                            },
                            "end_location": {
                                "lat": 54.73477699999999,
                                "lng": 55.972175
                            },
                            "html_instructions": "Поверните <b>направо</b> в сторону <b>ул. Мингажева</b>",
                            "maneuver": "turn-right",
                            "polyline": {
                                "points": "}jamIqgstIEjBG`B"
                            },
                            "start_location": {
                                "lat": 54.7347061,
                                "lng": 55.9732059
                            },
                            "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
                        },
                        {
                            "distance": {
                                "text": "91 м",
                                "value": 91
                            },
                            "duration": {
                                "text": "1 мин.",
                                "value": 46
                            },
                            "end_location": {
                                "lat": 54.734899,
                                "lng": 55.9708943
                            },
                            "html_instructions": "Поверните <b>налево</b> в сторону <b>ул. Мингажева</b>",
                            "maneuver": "turn-left",
                            "polyline": {
                                "points": "kkamIcastIB@DB@@@@?B@@?H?D?FAJQvAI|@Iv@"
                            },
                            "start_location": {
                                "lat": 54.73477699999999,
                                "lng": 55.972175
                            },
                            "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
                        },
                        {
                            "distance": {
                                "text": "0,2 км",
                                "value": 223
                            },
                            "duration": {
                                "text": "1 мин.",
                                "value": 64
                            },
                            "end_location": {
                                "lat": 54.7329662,
                                "lng": 55.9699862
                            },
                            "html_instructions": "Поверните <b>налево</b> на <b>ул. Мингажева</b>",
                            "maneuver": "turn-left",
                            "polyline": {
                                "points": "clamIayrtIn@RLFdCv@xB~@bA^"
                            },
                            "start_location": {
                                "lat": 54.734899,
                                "lng": 55.9708943
                            },
                            "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
                        },
                        {
                            "distance": {
                                "text": "0,8 км",
                                "value": 758
                            },
                            "duration": {
                                "text": "2 мин.",
                                "value": 141
                            },
                            "end_location": {
                                "lat": 54.7349762,
                                "lng": 55.9589906
                            },
                            "html_instructions": "Поверните <b>направо</b> на <b>ул. Революционная</b>",
                            "maneuver": "turn-right",
                            "polyline": {
                                "points": "a`amImsrtIAf@OfACb@SpBc@pGG`AI~@Ef@a@hFKrAOvBI|@QhBALIz@]rDKnAe@`FKxCIdAOXINIJCBSTA??@KHUJ"
                            },
                            "start_location": {
                                "lat": 54.7329662,
                                "lng": 55.9699862
                            },
                            "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
                        },
                        {
                            "distance": {
                                "text": "0,4 км",
                                "value": 369
                            },
                            "duration": {
                                "text": "2 мин.",
                                "value": 99
                            },
                            "end_location": {
                                "lat": 54.7380729,
                                "lng": 55.9594288
                            },
                            "html_instructions": "На круге сверните на <b>2-й</b> съезд на <b>ул. Цюрупы</b>",
                            "maneuver": "roundabout-right",
                            "polyline": {
                                "points": "slamIunptICCAACAG?GAG@G@MFCBABCFCNAHAJo@d@OTICSEwE}Ai@SOEoA]KE}@[UI"
                            },
                            "start_location": {
                                "lat": 54.7349762,
                                "lng": 55.9589906
                            },
                            "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
                        },
                        {
                            "distance": {
                                "text": "0,1 км",
                                "value": 101
                            },
                            "duration": {
                                "text": "1 мин.",
                                "value": 31
                            },
                            "end_location": {
                                "lat": 54.73719089999999,
                                "lng": 55.9590615
                            },
                            "html_instructions": "Выполните <b>разворот</b>",
                            "maneuver": "uturn-left",
                            "polyline": {
                                "points": "}_bmImqptITH|@ZJDnA\\"
                            },
                            "start_location": {
                                "lat": 54.7380729,
                                "lng": 55.9594288
                            },
                            "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
                        },
                        {
                            "distance": {
                                "text": "61 м",
                                "value": 61
                            },
                            "duration": {
                                "text": "1 мин.",
                                "value": 47
                            },
                            "end_location": {
                                "lat": 54.73732889999999,
                                "lng": 55.9581493
                            },
                            "html_instructions": "Поверните <b>направо</b> на <b>ул. Ивана Якутова</b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Пункт назначения будет слева</div>",
                            "maneuver": "turn-right",
                            "polyline": {
                                "points": "mzamIcoptI[tD"
                            },
                            "start_location": {
                                "lat": 54.73719089999999,
                                "lng": 55.9590615
                            },
                            "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
                        }
                    ],
                    "traffic_speed_entry": [],
                    "via_waypoint": []
                }
            ],
            "overview_polyline": {
                "points": "_lamIygstI`@FEjBG`BB@FD@D@Xg@xE|@ZdCv@xB~@bA^Af@SjBw@bKQ`CcA|Mg@pFi@bGe@`FKxCIdAOXSZYZa@TEE[AUHEFGVCTo@d@OT]IaGqB_Bc@iAa@UITHhA`@nA\\[tD"
            },
            "summary": "ул. Революционная",
            "warnings": [],
            "waypoint_order": []
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

Запрос:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?sensor=true&language=ru&origin=54.73489544, 55.97310594&destination=54.737,55.958
```

Comment: Ну даже не смотря на код, зная что `response.body` пустой, можно сделать вывод, что вы либо делаете не правильный запрос, т.е. сервер вас не понимает, либо проблемы с подключением.  Думаю, в том и другом случае у вас должен отработать метод `onFailure`  вместо `onResponse` , Ваши логи в `onResponse` отрабатывают ?  поставьте логи в `onFailure`

Comment: Так же возможно класс `RouteResponse` не подходит под ваш json, стоит и json тоже приложить. В этом случае так же сработает `onFailure`

Comment: Добавил JSON в код

Comment: Проблема в том, что я использовал код из примера. Но так к сожалению retrofit 1.7 использовался, я обновил код, но походу что-то испортил

Comment: Так значит всё таки отрабатывает `onFailure` ? поставьте в этот метод логи и смотрите что печатается

Comment: нет, не отрабатывает Log.e("Ошибка", t.getMessage());

Comment: т.е. отрабатывает Log.e("Тут", "Тут");  ?

Comment: Именно, и падает он на строчке, где используется response.body()

Comment: Ну я бы попробовал, получить сырой json и распечатать его , чтобы увидеть приходит ли он вообще по этому запросу.  В ответе к этому вопросу первые две строчки https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/840755/retrofit-2-распарсить-ответ

Comment: я с помощью PostMan проверил, данные приходят

Comment: Замените в APIService  `Call<RouteResponse>` на `Call<ResponseBody> `   и потом выполнив `String rawJson = response.body().string() ` распечатайте json

Comment: Ну так PostMan это сторонняя программа, все равно что в строке в хром ввели запрос и получили json. Это же не говорит что ваш запрос в APIService не содержит какой нибудь ошибки

Comment: кидает эту же ошибку на String error = response.body().string();

Comment: ну я считал, что если запрос неверный, то сработает `onFailure` .. А тут вроде видно, что какие то проблемы с запросом и json вообще не приходит, сервер даже не присылает json в котором сообщает, что ошибочный запрос. Такое ощущение, что делается запрос в никуда. Я сам только ретрофит изучаю, поэтому подождем, тех кто получше шарит. И для помощи себе же, выложите сам сырой запрос, может в нём ошибка

Comment: Не знаю, что вы под сырым запросом понимаете, думаю вы имели ввиду получившиеся ссылку?

Comment: Кстати еще: ваш класс RouteResponce какой то странный. В нем по идее должны быть аннотации. Чтобы автоматически создавать по json такой класс пользуются http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/     справа выберите язык, Source type: json и Annotation style: gson и вставляете свой json. Нажав на preview увидите как должны выглядеть классы вашего json для случая когда вы парсите его полностью. И тут вы можете сами убрать лишнее.

Comment: Ну сырой запрос.. значит что вы пишите в строке браузера, чтобы получить этот самый json

Comment: Но делать свой класс будите потом, сперва надо получить, что нибудь по запросу `Call<ResponseBody>`

Answer (score 3):

При любом ответе сервера - успешном или нет `Retrofit` вызывает `onResponse`.
`onFailure` вызывается, когда происходит исключение на стороне клиента (ошибка парсинга, отсутствие сети и т.п.).
Поэтому в `onResponse` нужно проверять ответ на успешность:

```
public void onResponse(Call<RouteResponse> call, Response<RouteResponse> response) {
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
         // выполняем полезную работу
    } else {
        // иначе смотрим что не так и/или выполняем действия при неудаче
        // для отладки просто выводим в лог
        Log.e(TAG, String.format("Error response: %d %s", response.code(), response.message());
        ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
        if (errorBody != null) {
            try {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error body:\n" + errorBody.string());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь можно в логах посмотреть что отвечает сервер и исправлять.