# Почему-то не работает кнопка android

Tags: java, android, retrofit

У меня есть приложение на андроид и почему-то, я кстати так и не понял почему, у меня не работает моя единственная кнопка, хотя все должно нормально работать я уже проверял как-бы, но при нажатии ничего не происходит.
Вот мой класс mainactivity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.developer_4.test_login.data.model.Post;
import com.example.developer_4.test_login.data.remote.ApiUtils;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;


public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView mResponseTv;
    private APIService mAPIService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        final EditText titleEt = findViewById(R.id.login);
        final EditText bodyEt = findViewById(R.id.password);
        Button submitBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
        mResponseTv = findViewById(R.id.tv_response);

        mAPIService = ApiUtils.getAPIService();

        submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String a = titleEt.getText().toString().trim();
                String b = bodyEt.getText().toString().trim();
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(a) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(b)) {
                    sendPost(a, b);
                    logs();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void logs() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://мой-сайт/v1/login/")
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        retrofit.create(APIService.class);
    }


    public void sendPost(String login, String password) {
        String a = "qwerty";
        String b = "abcdef";
        mAPIService.auth(new Post(login, password), a, b).enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Post> call, @NonNull Response<Post> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    showResponse(response.body().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "post submitted to API.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Unable to submit post to API.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void showResponse(String response) {
        if (mResponseTv.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            mResponseTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        mResponseTv.setText(response);
    }

}
```

вот мой интерфейс для работы с апи:

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
import retrofit2.http.Path;

public interface APIService {
    @POST("{parameter_0}/{parameter_1}")
    Call<Post> auth(@Body Post body, @Path("parameter_0") String p0 , @Path("parameter_1") String p1);

}
```

apiservice.java:

```
import com.example.developer_4.test_login.APIService;

public class ApiUtils
{
    private ApiUtils() {}

    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://мой сайт/";

    public static APIService getAPIService() {

        return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(APIService.class);
    }
}
```

может я не правильно настроил свой интерфейс, я уже не знаю что придумать, вот например если раньше я использовал всю информацию из этого ресурса: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sending-data-with-retrofit-2-http-client-for-android--cms-27845 если вы откроете этот сайт, то можете увидеть в конце статьи тестирование приложение то у меня получилось при нажатии на кнопку реализовать подобное, но дальше я попробовал сделать свой запрос на нужный мне адрес, и почему-то теперь вообще на сервер ничего не идет. Если кто знает в чем у меня ошибка то буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: https://habr.com/post/314028/ читай тут

Comment: `if (response.isSuccessful()) {...} else { /*прочитайте errorBody*/ }` и узнаете что сервер не понимает запроса на адрес `https://мой сайт/qwerty/abcdef`. Уберите к чертям эти плейсхолдеры (`{parameter_0}/{parameter_1}`) - Вы же не будете делать несколько авторизаций по разным адресам, адрес у Вас один его и пропишите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ApiUtils

Что это? Зачем? Почему? Что там внутри происходит?

---

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://мой-сайт/v1/login/")
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

retrofit.create(APIService.class);
```

А это вы для чего делаете? Собираете в билдере объект ретрофита, получаете инстанс вашего интерфейса и... ничего с ними не делаете? А откуда вы тогда берёте и инициализируете `mAPIService`? А зачем делать это каждый раз при нажатии, если инициализировать нужно только один раз перед использованием?

---

Нужно делать так:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://мой-сайт/v1/login/")
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

APIService mAPIService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

mAPIService.auth(/* */).enqueue(/* */);
```

Comment: обновил вопрос, вставил apiservice, а куда нужно вставлять mAPIService.auth(/* */).enqueue(/* */); и что писать в скобках, то что прописано в apiservice?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko просто скопируйте ваш код из ненужного места в нужное, и всё.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko вместо `/* */` подставьте свою логику.

Comment: я приблизительно понял что вы имеете в виду, в следующий раз буду задавать вопрос более точно.))

Answer (score 1):

Кнопка работает - не выполняется условие `if (response.isSuccessful())`, а альтернативный случай Вы никак не обрабатываете. Добавьте обработку неудачного запроса [(пример)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/847194/11515).

Адрес запроса складывается из `BASE_URL`, заданного при создании клиента, и пути, указанного в аннотации метода интерфейса `APIService`.
Плейсхолдеры подставляют значения в путь из `@Path` параметров метода - и того у Вас формируется адрес запроса

```
BASE_URL + {parameter_0}/{parameter_1}
https://мой сайт/qwerty/abcdef
```

а должен быть `https://мой-сайт/v1/login/`

Измените `APIService` так:

```
public interface APIService {
    @POST("/v1/login")
    Call<Post> auth(@Body Post body);
}
```

И, соответственно base url должен быть `https://мой сайт/`