# Передача логина и пароля Retrofit2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так. Создал запрос, создал форму ответа, но почему то приходит ошибка авторизации, не могу разобраться в чем ошибка, подозреваю, что запрос проходит не по типу ключ/значение. Интересует как вместо @Field передавать @Body по примеру https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814857/retrofit-2-with-only-form-data/37831830#37831830

```
 package com.thetehnocafe.gurleensethi.retrofitexample;


import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface JSONPlaceHolderApi {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("mobile/login.php")
    Call<Post> getPostLogin(@Field("login") String login, @Field("password") String password);
}
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String login;
    private String password;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        NetworkService.getInstance()
                .getJSONApi()
                .getPostLogin(login, password)
                .enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Post> call, @NonNull Response<Post> response) {
                        Post post = response.body();

                        textView.append(post.getResult() + "\n");
                        textView.append(post.getKey() + "\n");
                        textView.append(post.getMessage()+ "\n");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Post> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

                        textView.append("Error occurred while getting request!");
                        t.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

```
public class NetworkService {
    private static NetworkService mInstance;
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://my.ru";
    private Retrofit mRetrofit;

    private NetworkService() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor);

        mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client.build())
                .build();
    }

    public static NetworkService getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new NetworkService();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public JSONPlaceHolderApi getJSONApi() {
        return mRetrofit.create(JSONPlaceHolderApi.class);
    }
}
```

```
public class Post {
    @SerializedName("result")
    @Expose
    private int result;

    @SerializedName("key")
    @Expose
    private String key;

    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;

    public int getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(int result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getMessage(){return message;}

    public void setMessage(String message) {this.message=message;}


}
```

Comment: `@Body` не совместим с `@FormUrlEncoded`. Сначала определитесь что хочет сервер - форму, json или что-то другое.

Comment: я понимаю что `@Body`  не совместима с `@FormUrlEncoded`. на сервер мне надо отправить пост запрос в котором будет ключь/значение, в ответ сервер присылает json. так как щас написано у меня на сервер приходит пустой запрос. Делаю запрос через postman запрос проходит успешно думаю дело тут в том что я не передаю пост запрос в body. для запроса в постмане использую Body form-data key login value login  key password value password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, из Постмана вы отправляете `multipart/form-data`.
С учётом того что отправляется только текст - на Ретрофите это будет очень просто:

```
public interface JSONPlaceHolderApi {
    @Multipart
    @POST("mobile/login.php")
    Call<Post> getPostLogin(@Part("login") String login, @Part("password") String password);
}
```

**Update:** При использовании конвертера, Ретрофит может оказать нам "медвежью услугу" (обработать наши Part конвертером) - чтобы это обойти придётся сделать запрос по-другому:

```
public interface JSONPlaceHolderApi {
    @POST("mobile/login.php")
    Call<Post> getPostLogin(@Body() RequestBody loginBody);
}
```

Вызов:

```
MultipartBody loginBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
     .addFormDataPart("login", login)
     .addFormDataPart("password", password)
     .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
     .build();

 NetworkService.getInstance()
            .getJSONApi()
            .getPostLogin(loginBody)
            .enqueue(...
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, сделал как вы описали после этого щас у меня ошибка Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.thetehnocafe.gurleensethi.retrofitexample.Post.getVal()' on a null object reference, комментирую строку в которой ошибка и приложение нормально запускается без вылетов

Comment: Не знаю - надо видеть код и логи. На вскидку: запрос таки не правильный и сервер отвечает не `200 OK`, а что-то другое; или вы обращаетесь к `Post` за пределами `onResponse`.

Comment: ругается на    ```textView.append(post.getREQUEST_SCHEME());``` ```public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Post> call, @NonNull Response<Post> response) {
                        Post post = response.body();

                        // textView.append(post.getVal()+ "\n");
                         textView.append(post.getREQUEST_SCHEME());
                    }``` стоит её закоментировать приложение не вылетает, но и не чего не возвращает

Comment: Посмотрите в логах что отвечает сервер - у вас же `HttpLoggingInterceptor` логирует все телодвижения. Ещё не лишним будет проверять ответ сервера на успешность, что бы не получать всякие нульпоинтеры. Для примера: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/847194/11515